# adding a new SDK written in C into android

Tags: android, c, sdk

Is it possible for us to port a SDK written in C into android and used it to develop an apps? because I have a SDk written in C and wish to use it to develop an apps using it, how should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java talks to the native layer (C code) via the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html). You can use you C SDK if you write JNI wrappers for you API. This way you will be able to import you native library into Java and call your native (meaning C) functions from it. That's what the wrappers are for.

This will only work provided that your SDK itself does not use any libraries that Android doesn't support. If it's straightforward C and the GNU toolchain will compile it, it should work well.

In order to compile native C code for Android (or ARM to be more precise), you need the Android [Native Development Kit (NDK)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

This should get you started. There are plenty of great examples of how to use JNI and the NDK on the web, including Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Phonon, I was searching around and found NDK but couldn't really get how to used before reading ur reply. Will look on to the JNI. Thanks again